# Using/Merging multiple nested document sets in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a mapping type like below:

```
{
  "type": "NestedExampleType"
  "foo": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "keyword"},
      "name": {"type": "keyword"}
      ...
    }
  },
  "bar": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "keyword"},
      "name": {"type": "keyword"}
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write an aggregation that shows me the amount of `NestedExampleType` documents split by name.

For example, given the documents indexed below:

```
{
  "foo": [{"id": 1, "name": "aa"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bb"}],
  "bar": [{"id": 1, "name": "aa"}]
}

{
  "foo": [{"id": 1, "name": "aa"}],
  "bar": []
}
```

I expect to get the results:

```
aa: 2,
bb: 1
```

This doesn't seem trivial given the current way nested aggregations work. Does anyone have a good approach for this problem?

Comment: dont you want a `aa: 3` and `bb:1`?

Comment: @tomas no, because `aa` is being referenced in 2 documents (I am not interested in the fact it is referenced 3 times)